# What are the advantages of declaring method arguments __autoreleasing?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

As per [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> __autoreleasing is used to denote arguments that are passed by reference (id *) and are autoreleased on return.

For example:

`-(BOOL)performOperationWithError:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error;`

But what are the advantages of the above comparing to:

`-(BOOL)performOperationWithError:(NSError * __strong *)error;`

---

**Update:**

Several answers refer to the temp var trick compiler does to deal with the mismatch between var and argument as the *advantage* of `__autoreleasing`. I don't see why compiler can not do the same trick for `__strong` argument. I mean, for a `__weak` var and `__strong` argument, compiler can similarly do this:

```
NSError * __weak error;
NSError * __strong tmp = error;
BOOL OK = [myObject performOperationWithError:&tmp];
error = tmp;
if (!OK) {
    // Report the error.
}
```

Compiler knows `-(BOOL)performOperationWithError:(NSError * __strong *)error;` returns a strong reference(+1) so it handles it just like any `new`-family method. Since `tmp` lives in the same scope as `error`, compiler can reasonably keep it alive as long as `error` so the `__weak` reference(`error`) is now supported by a `__strong` reference(`tmp`) and will not be nullified until the end of the scope.

Comment: You try to manage the memory of a double pointer on your own and get back to us about why __autoreleasing is so awesome.

Comment: @CodaFi Even with __strong, ARC does the memory management for us, doesn't it?

Comment: Sure, but it makes the compiler's life a little more tricky.  At least with __autoreleasing, the tmp variable is added to an inner autorelease pool (because the life of an NSError is short).  If the pointer is strong it has to go through the work of figuring out the qualifiers for the second pointer and releasing the object associated with it.  Either way, you're right, but I'd rather go with LLVM's default __autoreleasing double pointers than anything __strong without just cause.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### tl;dr

Implicitly converting a `__weak` object to a `__strong` object in this case would alter the semantic of the program, something that a compiler should never do.

---

### The scenario

Let's take an example

```
NSError *error;
BOOL success = [myObject performOperationWithError:&error];
if (!success) {
    // Report the error
}
```

In such a case the `error` local variable is automatically inferred by ARC as `__strong`.

At the same time the `error` argument of

```
-(BOOL)performOperationWithError:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error;
```

is of type `NSError * __autoreleasing *`.

Please note that in any case ARC will infer parameters passed by reference (`id *`) as being of type `id __autoreleasing *`, so the above signature is equivalent to

```
-(BOOL)performOperationWithError:(NSError **)error;
```

under ARC.

Therefore we have a mismatch since we are passing a `__strong` annotated variable to a method expecting an `__autoreleasing` argument.

### Under the hood

In our example then the compiler will address such mismatch by creating a local  `__autoreleasing tmp` variable.

The code becomes

```
NSError * __strong error;
NSError * __autoreleasing tmp = error;
BOOL success = [myObject performOperationWithError:&tmp];
error = tmp;
if (!success) {
    // Report the error.
}
```

### An alternative

Let's now pretend that we can change the signature of `performOperationWithError:`.

If we want to avoid the "compiler trick" which uses the `tmp` variable, we can declare our signature as

```
-(BOOL)performOperationWithError:(NSError * __strong *)error;
```

We have a `__strong` variable and we are now passing it to a method expecting a `__strong` argument, so we just eliminated the mismatch.

### Looks good, why not always declare `__strong` arguments?

One reason is that declaring the argument as `__autoreleasing` will make the method to accept even a `__weak` reference.

It does not make much sense in the current example, but there could be cases in which we'd like to pass a `__weak` variable by reference and declaring `__autoreleasing` (or leaving the ARC to infer it) will allow us to do so.

ARC will apply the same trick seen above, creating a `__autoreleasing tmp` variable.

### Conclusion

The mechanism presented so far goes under the name of *pass-by-writeback*.

Such mechanism has been designed to work with `__autoreleasing`, `__strong` and `__weak` variables, so that the programmer can safely rely on the type inference made by the compiler and not care too much about annotating variables around.

Declaring a `id __strong *` argument may make sense in some cases, but in general it could lead to unexpected errors generated by the compiler.

My advice here is: "let the compiler do his magic and you'll be good"

### Update

> I don't see why compiler can not do the same trick for `__strong` argument.

Telling the compiler to handle in an `__autoreleasing` fashion the management of either a `__strong` or `__weak` variable it's ok since it basically means: "Please, compiler, do the right thing automatically".

That's why the trick seen above will work without issues.

On the other hand, if you declare a variable as `__weak` you presumably have a good reason for doing so and the last thing you want is to have it implicitly retained when you clearly specified otherwise. That would radically change the semantic of the piece of code you've written, therefore the compiler won't do that (thank God!).

In other words

`__weak`   --> `__autoreleasing` **good** 
`__strong` --> `__autoreleasing` **good** 
`__weak`   <--> `__strong` **wrong!**

Comment: My question is not "why not always declare __strong arguments?", but "why declare__autoreleasing arguments by default?" ARC can also apply the `tmp` var trick to deal with the mismatch between `__strong` and `__weak`, can't it?

Comment: If you read carefully you can find your question answered. Declaring `__autoreleasing` by default simply allows more flexibility. Of course you **can** do that, but having the compiler doing that for you is definitely more convenient and safer.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Then the problem is why `__autoreleasing` is more flexible than `__strong`? I don't see why compiler can not do the same temp var trick for `__strong` argument. If the advantage you are referring to is only based on that now compiler can only do the temp var trick for `__autoreleasing`, it is not a real advantage of `__autoreleasing` in my opinion, but a shortcoming of compiler.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Please see my update in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I agree the semantic is changed if compiler inserts a temp `__strong` var for a `__weak` var. This part cuts to the chase of my problem. Better answers come after better questions:) Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question -- specifically, nothing would actually go wrong in the __weak <--> __strong case (that I can see). Ownership would be correct; the retain for the __strong tmp ptr would be gone very soon; e.g. the compile could run "error = tmp; tmp= nil;" right after the call, thus sending a release to match the retain that was sent when tmp was assigned to.

Comment: To answer my own question: Maybe the ARC designers wanted to be nice to foolish coders who declared "NSError * __weak error;" and then passed in &error as an out parameter, in which case (without autoreleasing) they'd never see the error. With autoreleasing, they do see it until the autorelease pool is drained. But I'd say such a case is programmer error and not up to ARC to fix. The "fix" (if this is really why ARC is designed this way) costs everyone a lot of mental overhead to understand, especially since the docs are not great at addressing the original question here.

Comment: The whole point is that you don't want anything such a `__weak` to `__strong` conversion to be implicit, following the common sense that nothing of what the compiler does, should alter the semantic of the piece of code the developer wrote.

Comment: Messaging an object held weakly implicitly creates a temporary strong reference. It's probably not the only thing which does.

Comment: @KenThomases My initial statement is specific for this case. Also do you have a reference for what you are saying? I'm very interested in the subject.

Comment: I believe it's implicit in the defined semantics for reading a weak variable <http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#arc-ownership-semantics>. The weak reference is converted from an lvalue to an rvalue in order to pass it to `objc_msgSend()`, so it is retain for the duration of the expression.

Comment: Interesting, thank you! Still I think you agree that in this case the level is much higher than the runtime and that performing a "trick" as the one proposed by the OP would significantly alter the semantic.

Comment: @KenThomases anyway I'm not sure it's a implicit conversion from `__weak` to `__strong`. According to the doc, the value is just retained for the duration of the expression, but the ownership qualifier doesn't appear to be changed.

Comment: What else does a "temporary strong reference" mean? It means to retain the object and nothing more.

Comment: Ok, I suppose we can see it that way. I'm convinced :)

Answer (score 2):

The only advantage is, as you said, that the object is autoreleased on return. So without ARC it's the same as sending retain and autorelease. In C every variable passed as argument is copied, so this doesn't influence what will be done with the original pointer, but just with the copied pointer.

An example of advantage could be this, let's say the argument isn't __autoreleasing:

```
-(BOOL)performOperationWithError:(NSError * __strong *)error;
```

So I call the method passing a weak reference:

```
NSError* __weak error;
[object performSelectorWithError: &error];
```

What happens here? The copied argument isn't autoreleased on return, so when the method returns error is nil. If instead the method was this one:

```
-(BOOL)performOperationWithError:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error;
```

This case the error had still a retain count of 1, but it was autoreleased, so it wasn't nil and could have been used inside the pool.

Answer (score 1):

The other reason which I haven't seen mentioned is to follow Cocoa conventions so that ARC code can properly interoperate with non-ARC code.